# Android Expected a quoted string

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am doing android application. I am using ksoap2 to call my webservices. When I call the webservice it throws the following exception. Can anybody help me to fix this?
 **Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4111baf8)**

Log:

```
02-13 03:41:56.621 I/ActivityManager(  160): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.user.stub/.WelcomeMessage} from pid 322
02-13 03:41:56.671 D/ViewRootImpl(  160): pckname = com.user.stub
02-13 03:41:56.681 I/stub( 5367): WM - onCreate starts
02-13 03:41:56.731 D/OpenGLRenderer(  322): Flushing caches (mode 1)
02-13 03:41:56.781 D/OpenGLRenderer(  322): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-13 03:41:56.831 I/stub( 5367): WM - pack exist check
02-13 03:41:57.031 I/stub( 5367): WM - onCreate ends
02-13 03:41:57.031 D/ViewRootImpl( 5367): pckname = com.user.stub
02-13 03:41:57.101 W/InputManagerService(  160): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4121beb8 (uid=10026 pid=322)
02-13 03:41:57.141 I/ActivityManager(  160): Displayed com.user.stub/.WelcomeMessage: +469ms
02-13 03:41:58.451 I/stub( 5367): WM - onClick start
02-13 03:41:58.461 I/ActivityManager(  160): START {cmp=com.user.stub/.stub} from pid 5367
02-13 03:41:58.621 D/dalvikvm(  160): GC_EXPLICIT freed 521K, 23% free 10623K/13703K, paused 4ms+9ms
02-13 03:41:58.641 I/stub( 5367): IMS - onCreate start
02-13 03:41:58.681 I/stub( 5367): IMS - onCreate ends
02-13 03:41:58.681 D/ViewRootImpl( 5367): pckname = com.user.stub
02-13 03:41:58.821 I/ActivityManager(  160): Displayed com.user.stub/.stub: +315ms
02-13 03:42:21.561 D/audio_hw_primary(   85): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
02-13 03:42:21.691 D/dalvikvm(  288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 15% free 8064K/9479K, paused 4ms+4ms
02-13 03:42:24.581 I/stub( 5367): IMS - onProceed starts
02-13 03:42:24.581 I/stub( 5367): WM - getDyn starts
02-13 03:42:25.001 D/dalvikvm( 5367): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 7% free 7106K/7623K, paused 2ms+9ms
02-13 03:42:25.401 I/stub( 5367): WM - getDyn ends
02-13 03:42:25.401 I/stub( 5367): WM - uniqueId start
02-13 03:42:25.411 E/BluetoothAdapter( 5367): this device does not have Bluetooth support
02-13 03:42:25.411 I/stub( 5367): WM - uniqueId ends
02-13 03:42:25.411 I/stub( 5367): IMS - onProceed before call
02-13 03:42:25.711 E/stub( 5367): Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4111baf8) 
02-13 03:42:25.741 D/ViewRootImpl( 5367): pckname = com.user.stub
02-13 03:42:27.471 W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5367): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-13 03:42:27.471 W/InputManagerService(  160): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@412aaef8 (uid=10050 pid=5367)
02-13 03:42:27.691 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2849K, 40% free 8774K/14407K, paused 2ms+11ms
02-13 03:42:27.831 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 40% free 8774K/14407K, paused 120ms
02-13 03:42:27.841 I/dalvikvm-heap(  322): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.862MB for 1286224-byte allocation
02-13 03:42:28.041 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 403K, 34% free 9627K/14407K, paused 142ms
02-13 03:42:28.321 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1324K, 42% free 8455K/14407K, paused 64ms
02-13 03:42:28.321 I/dalvikvm-heap(  322): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.550MB for 1286224-byte allocation
02-13 03:42:28.401 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 33% free 9709K/14407K, paused 60ms
02-13 03:42:28.501 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_CONCURRENT freed 22K, 33% free 9712K/14407K, paused 3ms+24ms
02-13 03:42:28.681 D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1714K, 38% free 9047K/14407K, paused 2ms+5ms
02-13 03:42:29.711 I/ActivityManager(  160): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=ukzzang.android.app.logviewer/.act.MainAct} from pid 322
02-13 03:42:29.861 D/OpenGLRenderer(  322): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-13 03:42:29.931 W/InputManagerService(  160): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4121beb8 (uid=10026 pid=322)
02-13 03:42:32.551 D/OpenGLRenderer(  322): Flushing caches (mode 1)
02-13 03:42:38.871 I/ActivityManager(  160): Start proc com.google.android.gm for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailIndexerService: pid=5497 uid=10018 gids={3003, 1015, 1023}
02-13 03:42:39.101 I/ActivityThread( 5497): Pub gmail-ls: com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider
02-13 03:42:39.131 I/ActivityThread( 5497): Pub com.google.android.gmail.SuggestionProvider: com.google.android.gm.SuggestionsProvider
02-13 03:42:39.131 I/ActivityThread( 5497): Pub com.google.android.gm: com.google.android.gm.provider.PublicContentProvider
02-13 03:42:39.291 W/Gmail   ( 5497): No MailEngine for account: lance.pruitt.ibss@gmail.com
02-13 03:42:50.661 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 33% free 8158K/12039K, paused 4ms+14ms
02-13 03:43:29.691 D/audio_hw_primary(   85): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
02-13 03:43:33.931 W/InputManagerService(  160): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4141fde0
02-13 03:43:36.031 D/audio_hw_primary(   85): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
02-13 03:43:36.071 W/InputManagerService(  160): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41381330
```

Comment: "this device does not have Bluetooth support"
This might be your problem.

Comment: Please put the correct stack trace. The log that you have put does not have details on the exception.

Comment: @Manoj your problem is solved or not.?